# Programming ATMEGA328P using FTDI Failed

Tags: arduino, ftdi, atmega328p

[image]

I have a couple ATMEGA328P. I have the FTDI Module; now I can't get the FTDI to program the 328P.

I tried all connectivity schematics; I tried with different capacitors and I can't understand why I keep getting on IDE an error Message that it can not find the board or communication on assigned port.

I would like to know if there is anyway to test if the ATMEGA328 is actually in good condition. Is there a test I can do to verify?

Comment: How did you connect it? If with Arduino IDE, doesn't it require a bootloader on the AVR, so it can't program blank AVRs? Or have you built a ISP programmer out of a FTDI module?

Comment: Did you successfully program a bootloader? For example by using an Arduino as an ISP, such as described [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard).

Comment: plz check the photo i uploaded to the post , it explain my connectivity

Comment: This is the error msg i get

Comment: avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x30. 
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20. 
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x30. 
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20. 
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x30. 
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20. 
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x30. 
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20.

Comment: The setup from your drawing will only function if the ATMega328 has been programmed with a bootloader. Did you do that, or did your ATMega328 come pre-programmed with one?

Comment: You haven't pulled the reset line up with 10k resistor, your reset has floating DC component, it may very well cause random resets all the time. Try to put a 10k btw reset pin and 5V and see if it works

Comment: i have put the 10K resistor ..same issue again

Comment: (https://imgur.com/a/S50fwEA) check this out